# Dynamically changing pie chart for web page

Tags: jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I am creating a web page using `angular js`, `jquery` and `bootstrap`.

**Context**

- I have created a table and a form to insert values in the table.
- One column in the table consist of 'TYPE' that include one of the 3 options either regular or term or valet.
- Now I need to create a pie chart which will change dynamically according to the number of 'TYPE' present in the table.

**Problem**

There is no integer value present in the table, I want to create the chart on the basis of number of times 'regular', 'valet' and 'term' are present. I have surfed a lot on internet but haven't found any useful thing. Any suggestion for how to do this.

**My code is:**

```
<html ng-app="helloApp">
<head>
    <title>Fetch Park</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link
    href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
    href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script>
        var helloApp = angular.module("helloApp", []);
        helloApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.car = [
            { 'state':'MA',
            'plate': 'ABC-123',
            'time': '5/6/2016 10:00',
            'type': 'Regular'},
            { 'state':'NH',
            'plate': 'BDJ-675',
            'time': '5/10/2016 15:00',
            'type': 'Term'},
            { 'state':'MA',
            'plate': 'YHT-957',
            'time': '5/18/2016 12:00',
            'type': 'Regular'},
            { 'state':'MA',
            'plate': 'EST-856',
            'time': '5/21/2016 13:00',
            'type': 'Valet'},
            { 'state':'NH',
            'plate': 'EVH-475',
            'time': '5/25/2016 9:00',
            'type': 'Regular'},
            ];
            $scope.addRow = function(){
                $scope.errortext = "";
                if (!$scope.plate) {return;}
                if ($scope.car.indexOf($scope.plate) == -1) {
                    $scope.car.push({ 'state':$scope.state, 'plate': $scope.plate, 'time': $scope.time, 'type': $scope.type });
                }else{
                    $scope.errortext = "The plate already exists";
                }
                $scope.state='';
                $scope.plate='';
                $scope.time='';
                $scope.type='';
            };
            $scope.removeRow = function(plate){    
                var index = -1;  
                var comArr = eval( $scope.car );
                for( var i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++ ) {
                    if( comArr[i].plate === plate ) {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if( index === -1 ) {
                    alert( "Something gone wrong" );
                }
                var r = confirm("Are You Sure! You Want To Delete This Row?");
                if (r == true) {
                    $scope.car.splice( index, 1 ); 
                }
            };
        });
        function registrationFormDisplay() {
            if (document.getElementById("registrationForm").style.display === "none") {

                document.getElementById("registrationForm").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("registrationForm").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        $('#time').click(function() {
         var now = new Date();
         $('#time-holder').val(Date());
     });
 </script>
 <style> 
     .jumbotron {
        background-color: #f4511e;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 300px 250px;
        font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    }
    .container-fluid {
        padding: 300px 250px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl" id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">

    <div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center">
        <h2>Parked Vehicles</h2>
        <div align="center">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>State
                    </th>
                    <th>Plate
                    </th>
                    <th>Time
                    </th>
                    <th>Type
                    </th>
                    <th>Remove
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="comp in car">
                    <td>{{comp.state}}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{comp.plate}}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{comp.time}}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{comp.type}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeRow(comp.plate)"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
            <div style="padding-left:110px">
                <button onclick="registrationFormDisplay()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Parked Car</button><br><br>
            </div>
            <div id="registrationForm" style="display: none;">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addRow()">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">State</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state"
                            ng-model="state" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Plate</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="plate"
                            ng-model="plate" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Time</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" id="time-holder" name="time" class="form-control" ng-model="time"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Type</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="radio" checked class="form-control" name="Regular" value="Regular" ng-model="type"> Regular
                            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="Valet" value="Valet" ng-model="type"> Valet
                            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="Term" value="Term" ng-model="type"> Term
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">        
                        <div style="padding-left:110px">
                            <input type="submit" id="time" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="w3-padding-left w3-text-red">{{errortext}}</p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried doing it this way:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            size: 180
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            ['type',   'Regular'],
            ['type',       'Valet'],
            ['type',       'Term'],
        ]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Where is pie chart trials? Didn't you tried anything? Please add that if any.

Comment: You need to process your data, and get a count of each type that you want to plot - the chart won't figure that out for you. Take a look at this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502260/how-can-i-display-my-high-chart-correctly-and-import-data/33503130#33503130